# Hide div when clicking page body

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having difficulty hiding a div when clicking outside of it; the body.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
$('.list_container').hide().before('<div class="listbtn"> </div>');
$('.listbtn').click(function() {
    $('.list_container').animate({width: 'toggle'});
    return false;
 });
 });
```

I'm looking for to hide .list_container when the body is clicked, preferably it would animate toggle to hidden.

Comment: whats the problem?  are you getting errors?  what is it doing instead?

Comment: Where is the handler for the click event on the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind and event on the `document`, and prevent the click propagation on the container itself.

```
$(document).on("click", function() {
    $(".list_container").fadeOut();
});

$(document).on("click", ".list_container", function(event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Take a look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdiaz/THBht/)

Comment: `delegate()` has been deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and above in favor of the `on()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply an onclick to the document that hides the div and an onclick to the div that stops propagation or bubbling of the event to the parent:

```
$(document).click(function () {
    $('.list_container').hide();
});

$('.list_container').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```